# List slicing a json.loads file

Tags: python, json, list, slice

What this code does it gets the values of a json.loads file. It gives me a list of dictionary that are organized by dates. This code works, my understanding is, i am taking the the first value in the list of dictionaries, so the first dictionary, but shouldn't. `self.get_jsonparsed_data(self.ticker_text.get().upper())[0]` work as well? In my case it doesn't, I was hoping if someone can explain why I does not work.

```
def get_jsonparsed_data(self, ticker):
    #quote
    url = (f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote/{ticker}?)


    response = urlopen(url)
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(data)

def search_info(self):
    #self.info.delete(0, END)

    recent_filing = []

    for header in self.get_jsonparsed_data(self.ticker_text.get().upper())[:1]:
        recent_filing.append(header)

    ticker = self.ticker_text.get()

    #output dictionary values with proper format
    try:
        recent_filing_dict = recent_filing[0]
```

This works.
I get the first dictionary which is what i want but when i do `self.get_jsonparsed_data(self.ticker_text.get().upper())[0]` instead of `self.get_jsonparsed_data(self.ticker_text.get().upper())[:1]` it gives me an error

which pretty much is saying there isnt any values appended to recent_filing_dict. I was just hoping if someone can explain why?

Comment: Please show some sample data with expected output.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

"for" loops through iterable and `self.get_jsonparsed_data(self.ticker_text.get().upper())[0]` seemingly returns an item rather than iterable (list) while `self.get_jsonparsed_data(self.ticker_text.get().upper())[:1]` returns an iterable (single item list) which is iterated over by for loop

Comment: do you know where or what i can search to learn more about that. To be honest still confused.

Comment: slicing operation [] returns a list while indexing e.g lst[0] returns a single item from list